# How to open a url using an adress of an application

Tags: python, url

How to open a URL without webbrowser using Python, but with an address of the application with which I want to open it.

Comment: Take a look at ```urllib``` or ```requests``` libraries

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Access an API? Scrape a website?

Comment: Just to be clear: You are trying to open a *non-http/https* URI? For example, ``ms-chat:?ContactID=SomeOne``?

Comment: I was trying to open zoom without opening the webbrowser like using application address as i couldnt find a way i thought of finding a common way

Comment: Maybe that's what you are looking for: [Start a Zoom meeting from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1563255/start-a-zoom-meeting-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to do this

> Case 1: You just need to open a page. and that is it,

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://yoursite.com")
```

The above will open https://yoursite.com on your default browser

> Case 2: You need to open, as well as do a task eg refresh

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge("path to your edge driver")
driver.get("https://yoursite.com")
# The command below will refresh your webbrowser after 3 seconds of opening it
time.sleep(3)
driver.refresh()
```

If you want to use chrome... use `driver = webdriver.Chrome("path to your chrome driver")`

> Case 3:You have already opened your webbrowser (via selenium) and you are in another program and you want to see it without opening it manually

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge("path to your edge driver")
driver.get("https://yoursite.com")
time.sleep(10)
# this command stores your webbrowser window in a variable
main_page = driver.current_window_handle
# this command moves the webbrowser to the front
driver.switch_to.window(main_page)
```

- Also you have to install a driver for your browser if you are using the selenium thing...

> For edge go to [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#:~:text=Microsoft%20Edge%20WebDriver%20for%20Microsoft%20Edge%20will%20work,find%20your%20correct%20build%20number%3A%20Launch%20Microsoft%20Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Edge%20WebDriver%20for%20Microsoft%20Edge%20will%20work,find%20your%20correct%20build%20number%3A%20Launch%20Microsoft%20Edge). and choose your edge version...

> And for chrome go to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

- You will also have to do `pip install selenium` in the terminal...
  Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try selenium, although you'll have to first download Chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox() driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

driver.close()
```